# My action cant get data from a struts2 select tag

Tags: select, struts2

I'm developing a web app using struts 2 framework and i'm facing a problem with select tag in a jsp.
The select tag seems to work fine, but as soon as i press the submit button, my action cannot get the data from the select.
I have looked for problems about select, but all of them seem to be related with the list.
In my case, the list is shown fine. So, I'm quite lost and I dont know what should I do.

Here are my jsp code and my action code. When I press the submit, it suppose that the form will be sent to my action, and I shoud get the data from the form, but when I print the data is always null.

JSP Code:

```
    <s:form action="borrarCita" method="post">
    <s:select id="idCita" name="idCita" list="pendings" listKey="idCita" listValue="fecha" label="Elija una cita a anular"></s:select>
    <s:submit value="Aceptar"/>
    </s:form>
```

The action code:

```
public class CitasAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

private List pendings= new ArrayList<Cita>();
private String idCita;

private String desplegarCitasPendientes;
private String pedirCita;
private String consultarCitas;
private String citaAnulada;

public String execute(){

    return SUCCESS;

}

public String pedirCita(){
    setCitaAnulada("");
    setDesplegarCitasPendientes("");
    setConsultarCitas("");
    DbService db = (DbService)session.get("db");

        Paciente paciente = (Paciente)session.get("Paciente");
        List listaMedicos = db.getListaMedicos();
        session.remove("listaCitas");
        session.put("listaMedicos", listaMedicos);
        setPedirCita("ok");
        return SUCCESS;


}


public String desplegarCitasPendientes(){
    setCitaAnulada("");
    setPedirCita("");
    setConsultarCitas("");
    Paciente pac = (Paciente)session.get("user");
    Iterator<Cita> nombreIterator = pac.getCitas().iterator();
    while(nombreIterator.hasNext()){
        Cita primera = nombreIterator.next();
        if(primera.getStatus().equals("Pending")){
            getPendings().add(primera);
        }


    }

    setDesplegarCitasPendientes("ok");
    return SUCCESS;
}


public String borrarCita(){
setConsultarCitas("");
setPedirCita("");
setDesplegarCitasPendientes("");
System.out.println(getIdCita());
System.out.println(ActionContext.getContext().getParameters().toString());
Paciente pac = (Paciente)session.get("user");
/*
Iterator<Cita> iterator = pac.getCitas().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Cita primera = iterator.next();
    if(primera.getFecha().equals(getFecha())){
        iterator.remove();
        break;
    }

}


pac.setCitas(getPendings());

pac.getCitas().remove(getCitaSeleccionada());
session.put("user", pac);
DbService db = (DbService)session.get("db");
db.uploadPaciente(pac);*/
setCitaAnulada("ok");
return SUCCESS;


}

public String consultarCitas(){

    setPedirCita("");
    setDesplegarCitasPendientes("");
    setCitaAnulada("");

    setConsultarCitas("ok");
    return SUCCESS;

}

public Map getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(Map session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public List getPendings() {
    return pendings;
}

public void setPendings(List pendings) {
    this.pendings = pendings;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

public String getDesplegarCitasPendientes() {
    return desplegarCitasPendientes;
}

public void setDesplegarCitasPendientes(String desplegarCitasPendientes) {
    this.desplegarCitasPendientes = desplegarCitasPendientes;
}

public String getPedirCita() {
    return pedirCita;
}

public void setPedirCita(String pedirCita) {
    this.pedirCita = pedirCita;
}

public String getConsultarCitas() {
    return consultarCitas;
}

public void setConsultarCitas(String consultarCitas) {
    this.consultarCitas = consultarCitas;
}

public String getCitaAnulada() {
    return citaAnulada;
}

public void setCitaAnulada(String citaAnulada) {
    this.citaAnulada = citaAnulada;
}

public String getIdCita() {
    return idCita;
}

public void setIdCita(String idCita) {
    this.idCita = idCita;
}




}
```

So, to sum up, I have that select tag in a jsp and when a press the submit, the action doesn't get any data from the select.

I hope someone can help me with this because it's driving me crazy.
If you need more information, please let me know and I will try to post it as soon as posible.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is a part of the Cita.class code. Also it has the setters and the getters for every attribute.

```
public class Cita implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name="CITA_ID")
private int idCita;
@Column(name="FECHA")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fecha;
@Column(name="HORA")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date hora;
@Column(name="ESTADO")
private String status;
@Column(name="ESPECIALIDAD")
private String especialidad;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MEDICO_ID")
private Medico medico;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PACIENTE_ID")
private Paciente paciente;
```

And here is the struts.xml:

```
     <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="logger" class="interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="logger"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
        <action name="desplegarCitasPendientes" class="action.CitasAction"        method="desplegarCitasPendientes">
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
        <result name="success">/citas.jsp</result>
        <result name="login" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="borrarCita" class="action.CitasAction" method="borrarCita">
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
        <result name="success">/citas.jsp</result>
        <result name="login" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

@Jeroen, sorry for the huge wall of code. It was my first post here.

@Roman, I hope this helps you to help me :-)

Thanks for your replies guys.

Edit 2:

Here is my LoginInterceptor:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String intercept(final ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();        

    // sb: if the user is already signed-in, then let the request through.
    if (session.get("user") != null) {
        return invocation.invoke();
    }else{
        System.out.println("redirect");
        return "login";
    }
}
}
```

If you need something else, let me know :-)

Comment: Please post a short codesample that demonstrates the problem instead of a huge wall of text.

Comment: Post the `struts.xml` and `Cita` class.

Comment: @user2712493 do you have other data elements in the jsp..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a Interceptor issue.

What is `myStack` ?

Here's a sample stack I use in my projects (with Login Interceptor)

```
<package name="test" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
            <interceptor name="nlogin" class="interceptors.LoginInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="nlogin"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>

        <action name="test-list" class="actions.InboxAction">
            <result>/pages/inbox/list.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

loginStack is being used as the defaultStack for all actions in that package, because of `<default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>`

Comment: Hi, This last reply was useful. myStack is the name of my interceptor stack. I think that is not necessary to declare  a <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/> if you provide a <interceptor-ref name="myStack"/> inside the actions. Maybe I'm wrong?
But, yes, it seems a interceptor issue because I tried to remove the interceptor in that action and my action was able to get the data from the jsp.
So, I don't know if I have to do something special in the interceptor in order to make the data arrive to the action.
Any idea?
Thank you very much guys!!!

Comment: why don't you consider putting your myStack code here or just compare your myStack with the above loginStack, to check the interceptors sequence

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, It seems that I fixed it. Thanks to the coding_idiot's answer, I was able to figure out what was wrong. It seems that lack of defaultStack in my own stack was the problem. I just added the defaultStack and it looks like working fine now.
So, thank you very much to everyone and specially to coding_idiot.
The code finally looks like:

```
<interceptors>
        <interceptor name="logger" class="interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="logger"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```